# Docker connection refused localhost

Tags: go

My Application perfectly run on Ubuntu with these configurations

```
FROM golang:1.19beta1-alpine3.15

  
ENV CGO_ENABLED=0

ENV PORT=5000

ENV HOST=wizdwarfs

RUN mkdir /app

ADD . /app

WORKDIR /app

ARG WIZ_DIR=/app_data

RUN mkdir -p ${WIZ_DIR}

ENV WIZ_VOLUME_DIR=/app${WIZ_DIR}/apps.txt

 
COPY go.mod go.sum ./

RUN go mod tidy



RUN go mod download

 
RUN go build -o wizdwarfs 

RUN go test ./...


EXPOSE 5000

 
VOLUME [ ${WIZ_DIR} ]


RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates

LABEL designed="Wisdom-Enigma Inc"

CMD ["/app/wizdwarfs"]
```

`docker run --rm -hostname=wizdwarfs -p 127.0.0.1:5000:5000 -v /app/app_data --net=host -it  wizdwarfs/wizdwarfs-v0.0.2`

now I changed my OS ([deepin linux](https://www.deepin.org/index/en)) it throw docker `connection refused localhost:5000`. How can I resolve this error?

Comment: What throws the error? (something trying to connect to the app running in your container?). We would need more info (source code, logs etc) in order to assist (e.g. one, of many, potential causes could be that `/app/app_data` does not exist on your new installation). Please consider moving off the old beta version of go.

Comment: Since you're using `--net=host`, it's not necessary to bind port. Does it work if you change the port?

Comment: Let's figure it out !